# URL redirection if wrong url

Tags: django, django-urls

I have this method in my book model:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/book/%s/%s/%i/%i/" % ( self.book_title, self.book_editor, self.book_pages, self.id)
```

So the urls of each book are like this:

```
example.com/book/the-bible/gesu-crist/938/12/
```

I want that if there is an error in the url, then I get redirected to the real url by using book.id in the end of the url.

For example if I go to:

```
example.com/book/A-bible/gesu-crist/938/12/
```

the I will get redirected to:

```
example.com/book/the-bible/gesu-crist/938/12/
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create [custom HTTP 404 handler](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception).